# Docusign REST API approve/decline feature C#

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

We are trying to embed approved/declined tabs in our C# application. Were able to add other features such as sign here tabs as seen below.

```
Tabs tabList = new Tabs()
{
    signHereTabs = new Tab[]
    {
        new Tab()
        {
         anchorString = "~s1",
         anchorXOffset = -1,
         anchorYOffset =  0,
         anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent =  false,
         anchorUnits = "inches"
        }
    }
};
Tabs tablist2 = new Tabs()
{
    signHereTabs = new Tab[]
    {
        new Tab()
        {
            anchorString = "~s2",
            anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = false
        }
    }
};
```

But are unable to add approve or decline tags. Any help in this area would be appreciated.

https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf

Envelope envelope = new Envelope();

```
        envelope.Login = account;
        envelope.EmailSubject = "Please sign my document";
        envelope.EmailBlurb = "This goes in the body of the email";
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {

            signers = new Signer[]
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = "cmb@gmail.com",
                    name = "Chris Jackson",
                    routingOrder = "1",
                    recipientId = "1"
                },
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = "asc@gmail.com",
                    name = "Anderson Car",
                    recipientId = "2",
                    routingOrder = "2"
                }
            }

        };

        Tabs tabList = new Tabs()
        {
            signHereTabs = new Tab[]
            {
                new Tab()
                {
                 anchorString = "~s1",
                 anchorXOffset = -1,
                 anchorYOffset =  0,
                 anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent =  false,
                 anchorUnits = "inches"
                }
            }
        };
        Tabs tablist2 = new Tabs()
        {
            signHereTabs = new Tab[]
            {
                new Tab()
                {
                    anchorString = "~s2",
                    anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = false
                }
            }
        };


        // assign our one signHere tab to the recipient
        envelope.Recipients.signers[0].tabs = tabList;
        envelope.Recipients.signers[1].tabs = tablist2;

        // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft
        envelope.Status = "created";

        //*** Specify document and send the signature request

        account.Login() = envelope.Create(@"C:\Users\cberard14\Desktop\NewOutput.docx");

        Console.WriteLine("Signature request has been sent to {0}.", envelope.Recipients.signers[0].email);
        Console.ReadLine(); // pause to show console output
```

Comment: *"But are unable to add approve or decline tags"* Why? Did you get an error? Can you show the code where you tried to add these tags (tabs?)?

Comment: I am not sure how to add approve or decline tags for a recipient to select. No we did not get an error just was not able to find it. Is it possible to post example code for adding an accept and decline tab for a recipient to select in C# using the Docusign Nuget package. The only example we have been able to look at is in JSON and is not clear on how to do it.

Comment: If it's not coming up in your Intellisense then that means it's probably not supported in the [DocuSign .NET Client](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client) which I suspect you are using. It's an open source project so you can just add it yourself, or you can construct the raw JSON yourself and send in a request.

Comment: May be a subtle thing but please ensure that "Enable Tag Type Approve Decline" is checked in your account settings (Preferences -> Features -> Enable Tag Type Approve Decline).